# Julia type conversion best practices

Tags: julia, conventions, multiple-dispatch

I have a function which requires a DateTime argument. A possibility is that a user might provide a ZonedDateTime argument. As far as I can tell there are three possible ways to catch this without breaking:

1. Accept both arguments in a single method, and perform a type conversion if necessary via an if... statement

```
function ofdatetime(dt::AbstractDateTime)
    if dt::ZonedDateTime
        dt = DateTime(dt, UTC)
    end 
    ...
end
```

2. Define a second method which simply converts the type and calls the first method

```
function ofdatetime(dt::DateTime)
    ...
end
    
function ofdatetime(dt::ZonedDateTime)
    dt = DateTime(dt, UTC)
    return ofdatetime(dt)
end
```

3. Redefine the entire function body for the second method

```
function ofdatetime(dt::DateTime)
    ...
end
    
function ofdatetime(dt::ZonedDateTime)
    dt = DateTime(dt, UTC)
    ...
end
```

Of course, this doesn't apply when a different argument type implies that the function actually do something different - the whole point of multiple dispatch - but this is a toy example. I'm wondering what is best practice in these cases? It needn't be exclusively to do with time zones, this is just the example I'm working with. Perhaps a relevant question is 'how does Julia do multiple dispatch under the hood?' i.e. are arguments dispatched to relevant methods by something like an `if... else`/`switch... case` block, or is it more clever than that?

Comment: The optimal solution, if you can, is to modify your function to not care about the specific concrete type, but to work for general `AbstractDateTime`, without converting it to `DateTime` at all. Is that not an option? That is the general Julia philosophy, to make your functions as generic as possible.

Comment: Let's say I need to work with my DateTime in UTC. The DateTime function has a method which converts a ZonedDateTime to UTC with an additional argument. To avoid an extra if... statement, I would want to be able to pass either a DateTime or a ZonedDateTime to the method; however, this doesn't work since DateTime(dt::DateTime, ::Type{UTC}) is not defined. I can of course extend the DateTime function to add this method, but if method switching is done in if...else blocks in the backend anyway this seems practically the same (albeit a more Julian) approach?

Comment: Additionally, let's say I want to accept a string which can be formatted into a DateTime. The same question applies, and in this case AbstractDateTime will not catch both options, so I think the question above still stands for other examples

Comment: I don't really know much about DateTime, so my advice is a bit 'generic', but, as I said, implementing methods as much as possible in terms of `AbstractDateTime` would be preferred. If that is not possible, then I would add a simple shim that just does `ofdatetime(dt::ZonedDateTime) = ofdatetime(DateTime(astimezone(dt, tz"UTC")))`, or something like that.

Comment: BTW, Julia is compiled, so as long as your code is type stable, a fully type inferred version will be compiled directly for the correct input types. No if/else-switching in the backend.

Comment: I guess I don't really fully understand what it means for a language to be compiled: I get that there's a different version of the code which is run for different types of variables which are determined at runtime, but how a computer chooses between various options is a mystery to me. Thanks for that shim idea, it seems like it's closest to method two, so I guess that's the one of these I'll consider 'most Julian' if I run into other examples like this in the future!

Comment: Crash course for compilation: Compilation broadly means translation of computer code from one language to another. Actually, many interpreted languages do it too. We call a language "compiled" when it does a lot of optimization in the compilation. For example, type inference is part of the optimization.

Comment: 2. What DNF is getting at is interfaces (look up in Julia docs for examples). Your intuition is indeed correct that at some level you do have to write methods for your specific concrete types `DateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`. The question is how many *really*. Often most of your algorithms is shared between the two and can be written in generic `AbstractDateTime` methods. Those methods would call the specific methods for the needed data e.g. `Dates.week(t::DateTime)`. If you provide 2 similar working methods for the 2 types, someone could show you how to make it generic.

Comment: Cool, I'll look into interfaces, thanks! I'm still working on the function itself - when it's working for one set of types I'll try to write a few methods for other types and, if I'm struggling, may post it in an edit for guidance. Cheers again!

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the comments is correct that, ideally, you would write your `ofdatetime` function such that all operations on `dt` within your function body are general to any `AbstractDateTime`; in any case where the the difference between `DateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` would matter, you can use dispatch at that point *within* your function to take care of the details.

Failing that, either of `2` or `3` is generally preferable to `1` in your question, since for either of those, the branch can be elided in the case that the type of `df` is known at compile-time. Of the latter two, `2` is probably preferable to `3` as written in your example in terms of general code style ("DRY"), but if you were able to avoid the type conversion by writing entirely different function bodies, then `3` could actually have better performance than if the type conversion is at all expensive.

In general though, the best of all worlds is to keep most your code generic to either type, and only dispatch at the last possible moment.